# Find and return a pointer to a structure from an array of existing structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am getting an incompatible type error when trying to return a pointer to an already existing structure with an array.

Here are the relevant structure definitions:

```
typedef struct cust_t* Customer;
typedef struct item_t* Item;

struct item_t {
    int id;
    char *label;
};


struct cust_t {
    int id;
    int basket_size;
    Item basket;
};
```

As you can see, the structures define a customer who has a basket of items. So `basket` is an array of `Item`'s.

I then have the following two functions:

```
/*
Add data to the item with id item_id in the basket of cust
*/
void add_item_data(Customer cust, int item_id, void* data) {
    Item *v;
    v = find_item(cust, item_id);

    //Use the pointer to the item, v, and attribute data to it (unimplemented)
}

/*
Find the item with id id in the basket of cust, and return a pointer to it.

Assumes that the id of all items have been previously defined.
*/
Item *find_item(Customer cust, int id){

    Item *v;

    //Iterate over the length of basket looking for a match in the id's...
    for (int i = 0; i < cust->basket_size; i++){
        if (cust->basket[i].id == id){
            v = cust->basket[i];
            return v;
        }
    }
    //if the item is not in the basket, return null. program should not reach here
    return NULL;
}
```

You can see the second function assumes that the basket will already have a number of items already in there, with their id already set. The `void* data` will contain information like `label` and others.

My issue is in the `find_item` function, I want it to return a pointer to the already existing `Item` struct in `basket`, so `add_item_data` can use it.

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct item_t **' from type 'struct item_t'
v = cust->basket[i];
```

I'm guessing my pointer syntax is off somewhere, but I can't see where.

Comment: Emisor has highlighted the actual problem. I just have time to skim, but I think you've done this in a weird way. Maybe typedef the struct without the pointer, then have cust_t hold an Item* - don't use typedefs to "hide" pointers - If anything name those typedefs CustomerPtr and ItemPtr - the reason being you've dug yourself an extra layer of indirection without realizing it

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers. It obfuscates the semantics and eventually results in confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typedef'd `Item` as a *pointer* to an `item_t` struct. You have a similar situation with the typedef of Customer. This is awkward semantically. An `Item *` may be better interpreted as an array of Items, specifically a pointer to the address of the first Item in the array. If you're not familiar with that idea of arrays and pointers, here's a starter (for C++, but the concept is the same in both languages, the only C++-specific part is the use of `std::cout <<` to print to console): http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8-pointers-and-arrays/  (this and the next one, especially the part about the [] operator)

Your function `find_item` is going to return a pointer to an Item. And Item is a pointer to an item_t, so you end up with an `item_t **` type. A pointer to a pointer to an item_t.

v, as mentioned, is an `item_t **`, ultimately. cust is a `cust_t *`. In the if statement, you actually correctly use the concept in the link with: `cust->basket[i].id`

`basket` points to an item_t. You use the [] operator, which offsets the pointer by i, and then dereferences THAT pointer. In other words,`basket[i]` is the same as `*(basket + i)`

That means you get an actual item_t, not the pointer. Then right below it you misapply the concept. `basket[i]` returns an actual item_t and you're trying to assign it to an `item_t **` (hence your error). A cast doesn't help, that's not your problem. You're trying to turn an apple into a block of cheese.

I would suggest you start from the top and not hide the pointer in the typedefs. That makes this confusing to read. Based on your words, *"I want it to return a pointer to the already existing Item struct"* I think you've misunderstood what you've done. You're not returning a pointer to an item struct, you're returning a pointer...to a pointer to an item struct.

Anyways, you say you can't change the typedefs for whatever reason, so just to maybe get you at least working (though I'm not sure this will actually do what you think), change the return type of the function to just an Item, and assign the address of what you pull out of the array to v. Like this: (not validated, but hopefully you get the point)

```
Item find_item(Customer cust, int id){

    Item v;
     //snip snip
            v = &(cust->basket[i]); //using & as address-of operator here
            return v;
     //snip snip
```

edit: looking at your comments, I think you might not be familiar with the "address-of" operator. That's how you GET a pointer to something that exists. `cust->basket[i]` is an item_t, and the & gets you that item_t's address, which you can assign to an item_t pointer, which you've typedef'd as Item.

Answer (score 1):

`v` is a variable of type `Item*`, which is `item_t**`.

`cust->basket` is of type `Item`, which is `item_t*` and therefore any `cust->basket[i]` is an `item_t`

now you're trying to do this:

`v = cust->basket[i];`

I believe the error is clear to see already: As your error message points out, you're trying to assign a value of type `item_t` into a `item_t**` variable.

Consider not using typedef to mask pointers like that, so you can always tell at a glance if a variable is a pointer or not.

Comment: Does this mean I should cast `v` to an `(item_t**)` or something similar?

Comment: `v` IS already an `item_t**`. Instead, you probably want to change your `cust_t` declaration, because `basket` should be an array of `Item`s, not an `Item` itself.

Comment: also, both `v` and the return value of `find_item` should be `Item`, not `Item*`. At least, it'll probably compile if you do that, but i don't really know if that's what you intended to do originally...

Comment: @PythonNewb: **ONLY** use a cast iff 1) it is absolutely necessary **and** 2) You _fully_  understand _all_ implications **and** 3) accept them **completely**.

Comment: @Emisor I'm reluctant to change the declaration of `cust_t`, I've been given the code to build upon and don't want to accidentally break other parts of the code

Comment: Then `basked` is an array of `cust_t`, which means `find_item` should return one of those?

Comment: Changing the return value of `find_item` and the type of `v` to `Item` and then casting `basket->item[i]` to `(Item)` yields: "cannot cast to pointer type"

Comment: do not cast. typecasting is basically "reading a type as if it were another". It's not gonna help you here.

Comment: If I can't cast, is there any way to solve this problem without changing the typedef? Or do I need to delete my above code and try another way?